# Placing result count below Views exposed filters?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have a View, and I want to display result summary below the exposed filters. Currently I am modifying views-view--view_name.tpl.php.

How I can render result summary header just below the exposed filters?

Comment: How are you adding the Exposed filters? If you do it as a "Block" and place that block on your Views page above the "Content" block, it should get output above your view header.

Comment: Currently not adding as a block..Is there any way to render in tpl?

Comment: Please don't add signatures to posts (e.g. _Can you guys help me out?_), the question on its own is fine and we prefer posts not to be too chatty as it doesn't fit the format here. Thanks

Comment: @Clive, I will definitely consider this suggestion..

Comment: I got one solution for this one, we can render header area in tpl using
$view->display_handler->handlers['header']['result']->render(TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

Ad summary of the result in the head of the vieuw and reposition this div with css to the place where you want to put it.

Comment: That will be one solution but I don't want to do any css for this thing.